# Reverse for '###' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

The error im having is relatively widely discussed. I went through all of the privious topics but no solution seems to apply. The error is:

> "Reverse for 'favorite' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   [u'music/(?P[0-9]+)/favorite/$'] [15/Mar/2017 22:09:49] "GET
>   /music/ HTTP/1.1" 500 119546"

URL PATTERN

```
app_name = 'music'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
]
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<form action="{% url 'music:favorite' album.id %}" method="POST">
```

VIEW: 
   `def favorite(request, album_id):`

As you can see, I created the namespace, but django is still unable to revers the url. Can it be related to be direcotory of the template?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the answer! I cought the error. It was a faulty .html doc also pointing to my view.

I was looking for it for over 3 hours and ended up not going to the gym ... evil python!